# Using Bit-Vector Literal in Z3

Tags: c++, constraints, z3, constraint-programming

I'm getting started using Z3 with the C++ API, and I'm primarily interested in using its support for bit-vectors.

However, I'm completely stumped in trying to figure out how I can make use of bit-vector literals with expressions.

Here's the basics of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
context z3_ctx;
solver  z3_solver(z3_ctx);
optimize z3_optimizer(z3_ctx);
expr x = z3_ctx.bv_const("x", 256);
z3_solver.add(x == "#x4123"); // Need help here
```

There's no online examples showing how I can accomplish this simple task. If my bit vectors were merely 64-bits or less, this wouldn't be a problem, but I require support for greater bit vector lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bv_val`: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1context.html#a2bda3f1857cc76d49ca6f3653c02ff44

It comes with 6 overloadings, for all sorts of things you might start from. `int`, `unsigned`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, and even `char const *` etc. In this case, you want the `char const *` overloading, putting the value as a decimal string.

Comment: Is there no way to immediately input a hexadecimal or binary string? Seems like I'll need a hex to integer string converter.

Comment: Not unless it fits into one of the overloadings. Bottom line, you'll have to call something like `bv_val` so it can figure out how wide you want that literal to be. You can code up some helper functions for your use cases (128-bits etc.), but you'll have to do the string conversion yourself at some point.

Comment: Something is better than nothing, I guess. Thanks for your help.